# Can't remove Edit Links from copied SP 2016 site

Tags: 2016, navigation

Using ShareGate, I copied a team site from one SP 2016 site collection to another and activated server publishing on the new site, applying the master page from the new site collection. But I cannot seem to remove Edit Links from the Navigation. The other sites in the new collection do not show Edit Links by default. How can I fix the problem without the usual CSS hack to hide the link?

Answer (score 0):

This choice is based on permission what you have on each Site. If you have Full Control you will always see this choice. If you have Contribute or Read, you have not see this "Edit Links" option.